# Products are removed from mini cart after homepage load it doesn't clear if load another URL

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, full-page-cache, mini-cart

[image]

When I added products to cart it's added succesfully but when i click on homepage the mini cart become empty. what can be issue??

Comment: Sounds like your sessions are being lost. Investigate that.

Comment: @ProxiBlue it happen only when click only homepage or website load..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved this problem by disable a module full page chache (https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc)  but till now i doesn't find what was the issue with it.

Problem was When I added the product it's added but when I click on homepage button or logo (load website main url) it display no iteme in mini-cart but when add another product it's show all products that added previously ..

[here](https://gordonlesti.com/lesti-fpc-documentationversion-1-4-5/) is the extension documentation and code [here](https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc)..